# Load web resources (js, css, images etc.) from secure pages (https) by https NOT http

Tags: javascript, spring, http, https, apache

We have a big website with mix of https and http pages. And when i am on https page it tries to load resources by http protocol and some browsers block it as insecure (chrome for ex.).

So the question: how can i do some filter that allows me to load resources by https only from certain pages?

We are using httpd server and Spring security in our application.

So, how can i construct urls in JSP relative by context and by protocol? (I mean i cant simple write relative URLs in my page, because it is used in different contexts, for example
as example.com/resource.css and mydomain.corp/resource.css)

Answer (score 1):

Use scheme relative URIs.

```
//example.com/foo/bar/baz
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url context="/" value="/js/crypto/cryptobase.js"/>"></script>

something like this on all my jsp pages. How can i done it with scheme relative URIs?

Answer (score 0):

Get the protocol then load the assets you need. I think you should use `assertProtocolAndFilenames` in Spring.

Comment: don't know how to get it work. Pure documentation on this method and i think by its name (assert in it) that it is just tests something and fails if its wrong. So not my case, where i want to do some work. )